# .htaccess add / support

Tags: php, .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /myproject/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ $1.php [QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^books/([^/]+)/$ books.php?id=$1 [QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^books/([^/]+)$ books.php?id=$1 [QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^books/ books.php [QSA]
```

Everything works when I type: localhost/name
but breaks if I type: localhost/name/

What's wrong with my .htaccess and how do I add support "/"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need 2 rules and your 2nd rule has invalid regex anyway. Try this rule:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /myproject/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^books/([^/]+)/?$ books.php?id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/myproject/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: This does not work. It still breaks, when I type: localhost/name/, works if we remove the last /

Comment: this does not work, I tried the changes you suggested.

Comment: Do you have other suggestions??

Comment: ROOT dir, name is just an example. Most of the url_slug names are actually *.php files on the ROOT dir.

Comment: Can you copy/paste full .htaccess in question? Also does `localhost/name` work when you rename this .htaccess to something else?

Comment: localhost/name* works, while /name/ doesn't. In addition, the * name as described in this context is actually a different name for PHP files on the root dir.

Comment: I've pasted everything from my .htaccess file. Thx.

Comment: In root within that directory, sorry! In ROOT within that Directory, not on the wwwroot folder for IIS.

Comment: Try my updated code in `/myproject/.htaccess`. Also I trust you're not using IIS. This is Apache specific.

Comment: To proceed I need answers of **all of these** questions. Q0. What **full URL** are you entering in your browser? Q1. Is this the only .htaccess or do you have another? Q2. What is your Apache version? Q3. Does `localhost/project/name` work when you rename this .htaccess to something else?

Comment: Q2 = That's the only .htaccess file in that directory. Q3 => I haven't tested that.